# SQL Stored Proc Insert string with " and/or '

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to use PHP to execute a SQL Server stored procedure

My PHP is basically

```
$value = $_REQUEST['value'];
$query = "EXEC Add_Line @value = '$value'";
```

and my Stored Procedure is basically

```
@value text = ''

Begin
INSERT INTO MyTable (Value) VALUES (@value)
End
```

The problem that I am running into is that the value is a text field for height, so the general entry will be something like 6' 2".

My php query becomes

```
EXEC Add_Line @value = '6' 2"'
```

As you can imagine, SQL Server does not like this line at all.

I tried using replace(@value, "'", "''") in my stored procedure instead of @value, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try doing the replace in your PHP code instead...   Problem is that your value never reaches the stored procedure, SQL sees this statement as an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others looking at this for a solution, Sparky pointed out that the problem is SQL won't even attempt to execute the procedure because is sees the error. I modified my php to something like this

```
$value = $_REQUEST['value'];
$new = str_replace("'", "''", $value);
$query = "EXEC Add_Line @value = '$new'";
```

This work perfectly.

All credit goes to Sparky.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the replace in your PHP code instead...

Problem is that your value never reaches the stored procedure, SQL sees this statement as an error.

SQL -->  `EXEC Add_line @valud = '6' 2"`  and doesn't know what 2" means

by quoting it in PHP and passing the quoted value

SQL -->  `EXEC Add_line @valud = '6'' 2"'`  SQL knows how to handle it